# How do I set RKObjectManager's delegate to nil?

Tags: ios, restkit

I want to set RKObjectManager's delegate to nil. But I can't find delegate property.

My request is:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"getData" 
  objectMapping:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider 
                      objectMappingForKeyPath:@"clips"] delegate:self];
```

UPDATE: There is a crash in my app. I go to "Clips" and in the viewDidLoad send loadObjectsAtResourcePath.  If I rapidly leave this screen I get crash at [RKResponse connection:didReceiveData:].

Comment: RKObjectManager doesn't have a delegate. The delegate is passed to the RKObjectLoader and further to RKRequest. Do you want to set the delegate to 'nil' before the request completes? Try to provide more info on what you want to achieve, maybe is there a better way.

Comment: Yes, I want to set the delegate to 'nil' before the request completes.

Comment: I don't think that's even possible. Can you perhaps explain what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to somehow cancel the request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The crash is caused by your 'delegate' object being dealloc'd. There is a simple solution to your problem - just cancel all pending request eg. in your viewDidUnload (or dealloc, it depends on your implementation) method.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload 
{
   ...
   [[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] client] requestQueue] cancelRequestsWithDelegate:self];
   ...
}
```