# iPhone Restkit - Error at data loaded after back button pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, restkit

i found like my question answers, but my app stil not working.

I push view to controller-2 from controller-1. In controller-2 Restkit loading data, but not loaded, i quickly press back button to controller-1 and after few seconds app is crushing (Restkit loaded data).

I using ARC.

Please help me fix this problem. Thank you.

Comment: I believe this answer should point you the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574775/how-do-i-set-rkobjectmanagers-delegate-to-nil/8576230#8576230

Answer (score 0):

This happens because RestKit continues the network activity and then cannot find your controller since it has been closed and its location in memory deallocated. I'd suggest either adding some logic to prevent the user from hitting back while RestKit is loading data, or canceling all pending network requests like mja suggested.

One way to do this is to add the following line to `viewDidUnload`:

```
[[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] client] requestQueue] cancelRequestsWithDelegate:self];
```